# Does Win 7 Pro have a feature to automatically wakeup a hibernating PC?

Tags: windows-7

My computer hibernates quite quickly (where do I go to adjust those settings?) and while I like to save it from wear, I also want to wake it up from hibernating at a specific time to run some automation tasks.  Is there a simple app to do this?  Or, does Win itself have this feature?

Win 7 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

**Alter energy options:**
Press the windows button on your keyboard, type "energy" into the search box and open "Power Options". You can then edit your energy plan (mine is called "Balanced (recommended)") with a click on `Change plan settings`.

**Automatic wake up via BIOS:**
Some BIOS software supports automatic wake up. Search for "energy options" or something like that in your BIOS, but be aware that changes in BIOS should be done carefully and may cause serious problems that could result in broken hardware.
If you don't like to search that option yourself, you can write us your BIOS software and version, which is usual visible at boot time.
The most used BIOS software are:

- AMI BIOS (American Megatrends Incorporated)
- PhoenixBIOS
- Award BIOS

The version number is mostly written after the BIOS name.

**Automatic wake up via WOL (Wake On Lan):**
You can also use another device to wake up your computer if WOL is supported by your network card.

You can check if your network card supports this, when you're opening "Device Manager": right-click on `Computer`, click on `manage`, select `Device Manager`, search your network card and open the properties via right-click on the network card. Open the `Advanced` register, search `Wake-On-Magic Packet` in the list and set it to `activated`. Set `Wake-On-LAN-Functions` to `Magic Packet`. Click OK. Your network card is now configured to wake your computer up when it receives a "Magic Packet".
*NOTE:* these options might be called different because they depend on the driver for your network card.

To send a Magic Packet, you need a device or computer that is able to send so called "Magic Packets". Some Routers are able to do this and are mostly labeled with "WOL" or "Wake On Lan" functionality. Although, most routers don't provide options for automated Magic Packet sending some routers might do that. If not, you might be able to use another device or computer to wake your desktop up. To send the magic packet, you'll need the physical address of your network card, which can be found by running `ipconfig /all` on cmd.exe. You'll find your physical address, also called MAC address, in the output (see image below).

[image]

---

These two wake up methods are described very general. If you're willing to implement one of those, provide us with more details about the system that's used in case you need our help.

Comment: Yep, that's how it is. The BIOS option is the less complex one. It's just one option to set but you have to find it.

Comment: I didn't want to shock you. My explanations are very general. We can give you more detailed advices if you give us more information.